# Search replace query string with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have my site url like this.

```
https://example.com/page/1/?orderby=low_to_high&s=demo+post&post_type=post&twdg_wsac=1
```

I want to replace some part of this url using htaccess so the final output should be like this

```
https://example.com/page/1/?orderby=low_to_high&s=demo+post&post_type=post&custom_posts=1
```

So I have made changes in the htaccess file like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^&twdg_wsac$ &custom_posts
```

But its not working. Also as you can see in the url there is `twdg_wsac=1`. So the last "1" is a pagination for post so that would change dynamically as per posts count.

So can someone tell me how to do this?
Any help and suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks

**Update**
All the parameters in the url are dynamically generated I mean those are the filter parameters. So they cant be same except `twdg_wsac`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. twdg_wsac=1 mean "it is currently the first page" ? 
If yes, what about your url : /page/1/?ord... The /1/ doesn't mean it's the first page ? Do you have the information twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below, we are doing rewrite on query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=(.+)&s=(.+)&post_type=(.+)&twdg_wsac=([\d]+)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?orderby=%1&s=%2&post_type=%3&custom_posts=%4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `orderby=low_to_high&s=demo+post&post_type=post&` would be dynamic I mean they are the filter parameters so they would not be same for each time.

Comment: @NewUser try with updated, I didn't tried it yet if some problem occur let me know.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} twdg_wsac=([\d]+)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?orderby=low_to_high&s=demo+post&post_type=post&custom_posts=%1 [L]